# Rails - Create an object in database from nested params attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, nested-attributes, parameters

I have a rails application where the user creates a new job, and on the `job/new _form` i am having the user enter the information for the Company that the Job belongs too.

A job in the database is simply the Date it was created, the User who created it, and a additional foreign keys to tables like Company, Contact, Jobsite, etc.

A Company `has_many` jobs and a Job `belongs_to` a Company in my application.

So, before I can persist the Job into the database, I must first save the new Company so that I can then grab its primary key and put that in the Jobs `company_id` foreign key tuple.

I have everything coming back properly in the params hash like so:

```
>> params
=> {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"NiQO7Wlq87h3+YM//yIEMnctVKectfmZBb74suFOCcmg7g4YyCmGo2OiciOd3VuRDR52tKoE0v9nq1LYoTqHOQ==", "job"=>{"date"=>"2016-09-04 16:06:49 -0700", "user_id"=>"1", "company_id"=>"", "subcontractor_id"=>"", "jobsite_id"=>"", "companies"=>{"name"=>"Test Company", "phone"=>"(530)111-2222", "street"=>"3177 testing st", "city"=>"cameron park", "state"=>"ca", "zip"=>"95682", "email"=>"testemail@mail.com", "website"=>"testcompany.com"}}, "commit"=>"Create Job", "controller"=>"jobs", "action"=>"create"}
>>
```

And i can access the company information with `params[:job][:companies]`

So my theory is, in the Jobs controller, in `def create`, before i call `@job.save`, I must first do a `@company.new(company_params)` and `@company.save` so that I can save the company and then grab its primary key from the database.

But I need a little help with this.

Does anyone have some tips to give?

Edit:

This is a sample from my _form,

```
  <%= f.fields_for @company do |company| %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= company.label :name %>
      <%= company.text_field :name %>
    </div>
```

Inside the Job Controller I have,

```
  def new
    @job = Job.new
    @company = Company.new
  end

  def create
    @job = Job.new(job_params)
    @company = Company.new(params[:job][:company])
```

Job.rb has

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :company
```

And the params are:

```
def job_params
  params.require(:job).permit(:date, :user_id, :company_id, :subcontractor_id, :jobsite_id, :company_attributes => [:name, :phone, :street, :city, :state, :zip, :email, :website])  
end
```

When i submit my form, the attributes come back as `company` instead of `company_attributes`, so it is telling me "Unpermitted parameter: company".

The way i have it set up, `@job` has not function to do `@job.company.build`, they are not nested that way. Company is its own table and a company can have many jobs, and all a job can do is perform `@job.company`

Which is why i need to create the company first so i can get its primary key and then say `@job.company_id = @company.id`

I hope this makes things more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `nested_attributes_for :company` or `companies`, looking at your code and seeing `company_id`, I'm assuming it's `company`.

```
=>{
  ...
  "job"=>{
    "date"=>"2016-09-04 16:06:49 -0700",
    "user_id"=>"1", # <= Really shouldn't do this...
    "company_attributes"=>{
      "name"=>"Test Company",
      "phone"=>"(530)111-2222",
      "street"=>"3177 testing st",
      "city"=>"cameron park",
      "state"=>"ca", "zip"=>"95682",
      "email"=>"testemail@mail.com",
      "website"=>"testcompany.com"
    }
  }, 
  ...
}
```

Then in your permitted params you can do something like:

```
def job_params
  params.require(:job).permit(:date, :company_id, :subcontractor_id, :company_attributes => [:name, :phone, :street, :city, :state, :email, :website])
end
```

You can then use `fields_for :company` in your `form_tag`. Also, add a blank company to the new job action.

```
def new
  @job = Job.new
  @job.build_company
end
```

## EDIT

You can't use `@company` on `feilds_for` like this.

Perhaps `fields_for :company, @company`, but not just `@company`.

```
<%= f.fields_for :company do |company| %>
```

You have to use a symbol to represent the record's name.

Otherwise the fields name will be `"job[company]"` or in your case `"job[companies]"` instead of `"job[company_attributes]"`.

And either way, you can just add the new objects to the new job's association instead of adding an instance variable.

```
@job.build_company
```

You can try it out yourself with this working repo: https://www.github.com/frank184/surveysays

And for reference:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for

Comment: I am using a fields_for in the form_tag, but, it will only render the fields if i use "fields_for :companies".

Everywhere else i am using "nested_attributes_for :company" and ".permit(..., company_attributes[...])"

So in the Job controller it is yelling at me saying "Unpermitted parameter: companies" and i do not know how to fix this issue, which seems to be coming from the form_tag

Comment: @CodyPritchard post your form, your controller action and permitted params. Your problem is sending `"companies":{...}` in your params instead of `"company_attributes":{...}`. The reason the fields were not being rendered was because you need to send a new company with the new job (i.e. `@job.company.build`).

Comment: @CodyPritchard Updated my post